# Why does Swift infer the metatype 'Any.Type' instead of Type 'Any'?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, type-inference

```
func giveMeZero<T>() -> T? {
    print(T.self)
    return 0 as? T
}
```

When the above function is called without sufficient type context,
Swift infers the return type as the metatype 'Any.Type', where I'd expect it to infer 'Any' or maybe offer the ambiguity error.

```
// Calling code without type context, which exhibits the said behaviour
// prints 'no', since it's trying to cast 0 to Any.Type

if giveMeZero() != nil {
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```

Output:

```
"Any.Type\n"
"no\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why `T` is not `Any`

This is simple. There is no `==` operator defined for `Any?` and `Any?`, as `Any` is not `Equatable`. `T` cannot possibly be `Any`.

#### Why `T` can be `Any.Type`

This is also simple. There is such a [built in operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541152) that matches this signature exactly.

```
func == (t0: Any.Type?, t1: Any.Type?) -> Bool
```

#### Why it is not ambiguous

This is more subtle. You'd think that `T` could be `String` or `Int` or `Float`, right? After all, they all are `Equatable`, and for all `Equatable` types, [`Optional` defines a `==` and `!=` for them](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/2949362). However, it seems like that operators declared in the global scope are considered "better" than operators declared in a conditional extension of `Optional`, so operator overload resolution always chooses the non-extension operators first. This is reasonable - after all, adding extensions shouldn't cause old code to break.

As an example, adding this code would make your code produce an "ambiguous" error:

```
struct Foo {}

func ==(lhs: Foo?, rhs: Foo?) -> Bool {
    true
}

func !=(lhs: Foo?, rhs: Foo?) -> Bool {
    false
}
```

The newly added `!=` operator for `Foo?` and the built in operator for `Any.Type?` are considered equally good candidates for the call `giveMeZero() != nil`.

However, this would not:

```
struct Foo { }
extension Optional where Wrapped == Foo {
    static func ==(lhs: Foo?, rhs: Foo?) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    static func !=(lhs: Foo?, rhs: Foo?) -> Bool {
        false
    }
}
```

Comment: You say that there is no == operator defined for `Any?`. But `let a: Any? = nil ; print(a == nil)` does compile...

Comment: @MartinR Hmm, according to Xcode, that's using [this operator](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L474), which again, is declared in an extension :)

Comment: @MartinR So I wasn't wrong then. There is no operator defined for `Any?` and `Any?`. `_OptionalNilComparisonType` is not `Any?`. It's merely `ExpressibleByNilLiteral`.

Comment: But there is a `==` operator for `Any?` and `_OptionalNilComparisonType`, and that is what `if giveMeZero() != nil` could use (and it does so if you force it to: `if (giveMeZero() as Any?) != nil`). Perhaps I am misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @MartinR Ah I see where you are confused. That operator is also declared in an extension, just like how `==(String?, String?)` and `==(Int?, Int?)` are declared in an extension. From what I observed, given a set of applicable operators, operators not in extensions are consistently preferred over operators declared in extensions (though I didn't try to find a source for this). This makes sense because otherwise, adding operators in extensions would break existing code.